# how to return the looped values in a method in python/django that no using array

Tags: python, django, arrays

how can I return a looped values in a method that no using array, for now i am using an array.

here is my code :

```
def get_ticket_sum_quantity(self, product_id, date_select):
    prod = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
    sumOfQuantity = Ticket.objects.filter(date_select=date_select, product=prod).aggregate(Sum('quantity'))['quantity__sum']    
    if sumOfQuantity == None:
        sumOfQuantity = 0
    prodAvailable = prod.quantity - sumOfQuantity
    return prodAvailable 
def get_ticket_available_product(self, date_select, client_id, quantity):
    client = Client.objects.get(id=client_id)
    prodCount = Product.objects.filter(client=client_id,status='Active').values_list('id', flat=True)
    array = []
    for id in prodCount:
        prodAvailable = Ticket.objects.get_ticket_sum_quantity(id, date_select)
        prodAvailable = prodAvailable - quantity
        if prodAvailable < 0:
            data = {'id':id}
        else :
            data = {'id':id}
            data = data['id']
            array.append(data)
    return array
```

and when i used it and the out-put is...

```
Ticket.objects.get_ticket_available_product('2011-12-29', 5, 1)
[3, 2, 6, 1]
```

my question is, is there any other options that I will be not using an array so that it will return like this?

```
3
2
6
1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use

1. **Either** convert your function to a generator, so that after each invocation it returns the next value or Generates StopIteration if there is no value to return.

   ```
   def get_ticket_available_product(self, date_select, client_id, quantity):
       client = Client.objects.get(id=client_id)
       prodCount = Product.objects.filter(client=client_id,status='Active').values_list('id', flat=True)
       for id in prodCount:
           prodAvailable = Ticket.objects.get_ticket_sum_quantity(id, date_select)
           prodAvailable = prodAvailable - quantity
           if prodAvailable < 0:
               data = {'id':id}
           else :
               data = {'id':id}
               data = data['id']
               yield data
       return
   ```

Usage

```
data = get_ticket_available_product(self, date_select, client_id, quantity)
for d in data:
    print d
```

1. **Or You** can also split the returned list in the manner desired

Example

```
print '\n'.join(str(i) for i in [3, 2, 6, 1])
```

or as in this case

```
print '\n'.join(str(i) for i in Ticket.objects.get_ticket_available_product('2011-12-29', 5, 1) )
```

1. **Or You can** split the return value in this manner. Remember in that case the return value would be a string

   ```
       data = data['id']
           array.append(data)
   return '\n'.join(str(i) for i in array )
   ```

Usage:

```
print Ticket.objects.get_ticket_available_product('2011-12-29', 5, 1)
```

Btw:

What is the purpose of this code snippet?

```
if prodAvailable < 0:
    data = {'id':id}
```

Comment: i use it if the prodAvialable is negative then it will not be included to be return.